# groovy script + set ENV for groovy

Tags: groovy

My target is to write groovy scripts under Linux 5.1

So first I install groovy and other as the following:

1. First I installed java /home/jdk1.6.0_12
2. Second I download groovy-1.8.0 and perform unzip under /usr/share
3. Third I download apache-ant-1.8.2 and perform unzip under /usr/share

So I get the following under /usr/share directory

```
   apache-ant-1.8.2
   groovy-1.8.0
```

My question is what the next steps that I need to do? In order to set groovy environment and begin run groovy scripts ?
Please advice also about simple groovy script for example

THX

Answer (score 3):

add the following environment variables

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/jdk1.6.0_12
export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/share/groovy-1.8.0
export PATH=$PATH:$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

to test if everything is working create a file 'Foo.groovy` containing this text:

```
println 'it works'
```

and execute the command `groovy Foo.groovy`. If this prints 'it works', then you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check whether their is a Groovy package available in your distribution's package repository. I know there are binary packages for Debian and Ubuntu, as well as a source package in the ArchLinux AUR. Using your distribution's package manager is generally the easiest way to install things. It will also make it easier to uninstall it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
verify the groovy version set in your linux box
    [root@anish ~]# set | grep -i groovy
    GROOVY_HOME=/opt/groovy-1.7.2
    GROOVY_JAR=/opt/groovy-1.7.2/embeddable/groovy-all-1.7.2.jar
    GROOVY_SRC=/opt/groovy-1.7.2/src

println 'it works'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GVM to install groovy.  Easier to install, update and maintain for long term. http://gvmtool.net/